# Updating a query each time that a new character is typed in into an input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following code to perform an auto-completion for an input when introducing characters.

The problem I'm having is that with this function if I type in "En" it returns not only all the words starting with "En" (example: English, England, Enterprise, etc) but any word that contains the string of characters "En" anywhere (example: cENtral, cENtury, calENdar, etc)

What change do I need to make in my code to get only those words that start with the characters I type in?

It seams that the query is not getting update each time I introduce a character.

My Code:

```
<?php

include("config.php");

    $db = pg_connect("$db_host $db_name $db_username $db_password");

    $termfilter = $GET['term'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE city LIKE '$termfilter%'";
    $result = pg_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>";
        echo pg_last_error();
        exit();
    }

    $get_total_rows = pg_numrows($result);
    $i =  $get_total_rows; 

while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $city = $myrow[city];
    $country = $myrow[country];
    if ($i == $get_total_rows){
        $list = "'" . $city . " (" . $country . ")'";
        $i = $i -1;
    }
    else {$list = $list . ", '" . $city . " (" . $country . ")'";} 
     }

?>

<center>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="searchresults.php" >
    <input id="hero-demo" autofocus type="search" name="search" placeholder="City" >
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.auto-complete.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#hero-demo').autoComplete({
            minChars: 2,
            source: function(term, suggest){
                term = term.toLowerCase();
                var choices = [<?= $list ?>];
                var suggestions = [];
                for (i=0;i<choices.length;i++)
                    if (~choices[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(term)) suggestions.push(choices[i]);
                suggest(suggestions);
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

My question is how do I get

$termfilter = $GET['term']; from   so each time a new letter is type in, the query is execute and the value typed in is passed to  $termfilter = $GET['term'];?

Additional code from the js/jquery.auto-complete.js file in case is need it

```
(function($){
$.fn.autoComplete = function(options){
    var o = $.extend({}, $.fn.autoComplete.defaults, options);

    // public methods
    if (typeof options == 'string') {
        this.each(function(){
            var that = $(this);
            if (options == 'destroy') {
                $(window).off('resize.autocomplete', that.updateSC);
                that.off('blur.autocomplete focus.autocomplete keydown.autocomplete keyup.autocomplete');
                if (that.data('autocomplete'))
                    that.attr('autocomplete', that.data('autocomplete'));
                else
                    that.removeAttr('autocomplete');
                $(that.data('sc')).remove();
                that.removeData('sc').removeData('autocomplete');
            }
        });
        return this;
    }

    return this.each(function(){
        var that = $(this);
        // sc = 'suggestions container'
        that.sc = $('<div class="autocomplete-suggestions '+o.menuClass+'"></div>');
        that.data('sc', that.sc).data('autocomplete', that.attr('autocomplete'));
        that.attr('autocomplete', 'off');
        that.cache = {};
        that.last_val = '';

        that.updateSC = function(resize, next){
            that.sc.css({
                top: that.offset().top + that.outerHeight(),
                left: that.offset().left,
                width: that.outerWidth()
            });
            if (!resize) {
                that.sc.show();
                if (!that.sc.maxHeight) that.sc.maxHeight = parseInt(that.sc.css('max-height'));
                if (!that.sc.suggestionHeight) that.sc.suggestionHeight = $('.autocomplete-suggestion', that.sc).first().outerHeight();
                if (that.sc.suggestionHeight)
                    if (!next) that.sc.scrollTop(0);
                    else {
                        var scrTop = that.sc.scrollTop(), selTop = next.offset().top - that.sc.offset().top;
                        if (selTop + that.sc.suggestionHeight - that.sc.maxHeight > 0)
                            that.sc.scrollTop(selTop + that.sc.suggestionHeight + scrTop - that.sc.maxHeight);
                        else if (selTop < 0)
                            that.sc.scrollTop(selTop + scrTop);
                    }
            }
        }
        $(window).on('resize.autocomplete', that.updateSC);

        that.sc.appendTo('body');

        that.sc.on('mouseleave', '.autocomplete-suggestion', function (){
            $('.autocomplete-suggestion.selected').removeClass('selected');
        });

        that.sc.on('mouseenter', '.autocomplete-suggestion', function (){
            $('.autocomplete-suggestion.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        });

        that.sc.on('mousedown click', '.autocomplete-suggestion', function (e){
            var item = $(this), v = item.data('val');
            if (v || item.hasClass('autocomplete-suggestion')) { // else outside click
                that.val(v);
                o.onSelect(e, v, item);
                that.sc.hide();
            }
            return false;
        });

        that.on('blur.autocomplete', function(){
            try { over_sb = $('.autocomplete-suggestions:hover').length; } catch(e){ over_sb = 0; } // IE7 fix :hover
            if (!over_sb) {
                that.last_val = that.val();
                that.sc.hide();
                setTimeout(function(){ that.sc.hide(); }, 350); // hide suggestions on fast input
            } else if (!that.is(':focus')) setTimeout(function(){ that.focus(); }, 20);
        });

        if (!o.minChars) that.on('focus.autocomplete', function(){ that.last_val = '\n'; that.trigger('keyup.autocomplete'); });

        function suggest(data){
            var val = that.val();
            that.cache[val] = data;
            if (data.length && val.length >= o.minChars) {
                var s = '';
                for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) s += o.renderItem(data[i], val);
                that.sc.html(s);
                that.updateSC(0);
            }
            else
                that.sc.hide();
        }

        that.on('keydown.autocomplete', function(e){
            // down (40), up (38)
            if ((e.which == 40 || e.which == 38) && that.sc.html()) {
                var next, sel = $('.autocomplete-suggestion.selected', that.sc);
                if (!sel.length) {
                    next = (e.which == 40) ? $('.autocomplete-suggestion', that.sc).first() : $('.autocomplete-suggestion', that.sc).last();
                    that.val(next.addClass('selected').data('val'));
                } else {
                    next = (e.which == 40) ? sel.next('.autocomplete-suggestion') : sel.prev('.autocomplete-suggestion');
                    if (next.length) { sel.removeClass('selected'); that.val(next.addClass('selected').data('val')); }
                    else { sel.removeClass('selected'); that.val(that.last_val); next = 0; }
                }
                that.updateSC(0, next);
                return false;
            }
            // esc
            else if (e.which == 27) that.val(that.last_val).sc.hide();
            // enter or tab
            else if (e.which == 13 || e.which == 9) {
                var sel = $('.autocomplete-suggestion.selected', that.sc);
                if (sel.length && that.sc.is(':visible')) { o.onSelect(e, sel.data('val'), sel); setTimeout(function(){ that.sc.hide(); }, 20); }
            }
        });

        that.on('keyup.autocomplete', function(e){
            if (!~$.inArray(e.which, [13, 27, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40])) {
                var val = that.val();
                if (val.length >= o.minChars) {
                    if (val != that.last_val) {
                        that.last_val = val;
                        clearTimeout(that.timer);
                        if (o.cache) {
                            if (val in that.cache) { suggest(that.cache[val]); return; }
                            // no requests if previous suggestions were empty
                            for (var i=1; i<val.length-o.minChars; i++) {
                                var part = val.slice(0, val.length-i);
                                if (part in that.cache && !that.cache[part].length) { suggest([]); return; }
                            }
                        }
                        that.timer = setTimeout(function(){ o.source(val, suggest) }, o.delay);
                    }
                } else {
                    that.last_val = val;
                    that.sc.hide();
                }
            }
        });
    });
}

$.fn.autoComplete.defaults = {
    source: 0,
    minChars: 3,
    delay: 150,
    cache: 1,
    menuClass: '',
    renderItem: function (item, search){
        // escape special characters
        search = search.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
        var re = new RegExp("(" + search.split(' ').join('|') + ")", "gi");
        return '<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-val="' + item + '">' + item.replace(re, "<b>$1</b>") + '</div>';
    },
    onSelect: function(e, term, item){}
};
}(jQuery));
```

Thanks

Comment: Look at what the PHP `index` function does, since that is what is doing the matching.  The JavaScript code simply displays what it is given, and you can verify this yourself if you look at the brower's network tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What change do I need to make in my code to get only those words that start with the characters I type in?

This line of code pushes a choice into the suggestion list if `term` matches anywhere in `choices[i]`:

```
if (~choices[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(term)) suggestions.push(choices[i]);
```

What you want is to push it to the list only if `choices[i]` matches the beginning of `term`:

```
if (choices[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(term) === 0) suggestions.push(choices[i]);
```

(Meanwhile, you have other stuff going on serverside that I'm honestly not quite following.  If you're requesting the full list of data once, and then doing the per-keystroke autocomplete suggestions against that full list in javascript, then you should be all good.  But if you're trying to make new server requests on every keystroke, and/or are attempting to do the filtering both server- and client-side, then... don't do that; it's going to be laggy and unresponsive.)

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel, that solve my issue and now I'm getting only the cities starting with the string introduce.  Going back to the question of the $list variable. If I introduce let's say 800 city names in the $list then the code doesn't work. I'm guessing because the variable $list cannot store that many characters. It is any way to store them in an array or any other way so I can pass as many var choices a large amount of cities? Thank you very much again for your help

Comment: I very much doubt you're overrunning the available length of a string with 800 city names -- an unescaped apostrophe in one of the names seems much more likely to be the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much everything works great now. Actually I can fit over 3500 cities. The issue as you stated it was a country having an '  in the name. Thank you so much gain

Answer (score 0):

Many changes needed in your code,one change here, use quotes

```
$city = $myrow["city"];
$country = $myrow["country"];
```

Are you sure about the query or it should be

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE city LIKE '%$termfilter%'";
```

Also use full php code `<?php   ?>` not `<?=   ?>`